# Convert a BTRFS subvolume to a normal directory

Tags: btrfs

So, let's say I have a BTRFS subvolume on the root subvolume that I wish to convert to a normal directory as quickly as possible, while also keeping hardlinks and reflinks intact. Is there an easy way to do this? I can't find any documentation on how to do this easily in seconds, especially if it's a large subvolume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `mv`ing the content should work. In this regard a subvolume is not much more than a directory. I made a simple test for things like hardlinks and just a plain move worked as desired.

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ btrfs subvolume create sub
Create subvolume './sub'
$ echo 1 > file
$ ln file hard
$ echo 2 >> hard
$ cat file
1
2
$ ls -1i file hard
20803239 file
20803239 hard
# create 5 Gb file with random data to see if it later moves (fast) or copies (slower)
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=rand bs=1G count=5
$ btrfs filesystem du rand
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
   5.00GiB     5.00GiB       0.00B  rand
$ cp --reflink=always rand rand-ref
$ echo something >> rand-ref
$ btrfs filesystem du rand
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
   5.00GiB       0.00B     5.00GiB  rand
$ btrfs filesystem du rand-ref
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
   5.00GiB     4.00KiB     5.00GiB  rand-ref
$ truncate -s 10G sparse
$ btrfs filesystem du sparse
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
     0.00B       0.00B       0.00B  sparse
$ ls
file  hard  rand  rand-ref  sparse  sub
```

now move anything into the subvolume 'sub'

```
$ mv file hard rand rand-ref sparse sub/
```

and check result

```
$ ls -1i file hard
257 file
257 hard
$ btrfs filesystem du rand rand-ref sparse
     Total   Exclusive  Set shared  Filename
   5.00GiB       0.00B     5.00GiB  rand
   5.00GiB     4.00KiB     5.00GiB  rand-ref
     0.00B       0.00B       0.00B  sparse
```

PS: since you want to convert the subvolume. I don't think there is a command to do it inplace. Move content somewhere else, than delete empty subvolume and move content back in place.